# Getting a specific child node from XML JAVA

Tags: java, xml, filereader

```
<DistinctParty FixedRef="10569">
      <Comment />
      <Profile ID="10569" PartySubTypeID="4">
        <Identity ID="952" FixedRef="10569" Primary="true" False="false">
          <Alias FixedRef="10569" AliasTypeID="1403" Primary="true" LowQuality="false">
            <DocumentedName ID="952" FixedRef="10569" DocNameStatusID="1">
              <DocumentedNamePart>
                <NamePartValue NamePartGroupID="36916" ScriptID="215" ScriptStatusID="1" Acronym="false">MAKHLUF</NamePartValue>
              </DocumentedNamePart>
              <DocumentedNamePart>
                <NamePartValue NamePartGroupID="36917" ScriptID="215" ScriptStatusID="1" Acronym="false">Hafiz</NamePartValue>
              </DocumentedNamePart>
            </DocumentedName>
          </Alias>
          <Alias FixedRef="10569" AliasTypeID="1400" Primary="false" LowQuality="false">
            <DocumentedName ID="12197" FixedRef="10569" DocNameStatusID="2">
              <DocumentedNamePart>
                <NamePartValue NamePartGroupID="18042" ScriptID="215" ScriptStatusID="1" Acronym="false">MAKHLOUF</NamePartValue>
              </DocumentedNamePart>
              <DocumentedNamePart>
                <NamePartValue NamePartGroupID="18043" ScriptID="215" ScriptStatusID="1" Acronym="false">Hafez</NamePartValue>
              </DocumentedNamePart>
            </DocumentedName>
          </Alias>
          <NamePartGroups>
            <MasterNamePartGroup>
              <NamePartGroup ID="36916" NamePartTypeID="1520" />
            </MasterNamePartGroup>
            <MasterNamePartGroup>
              <NamePartGroup ID="36917" NamePartTypeID="1521" />
            </MasterNamePartGroup>
            <MasterNamePartGroup>
              <NamePartGroup ID="18042" NamePartTypeID="1520" />
            </MasterNamePartGroup>
            <MasterNamePartGroup>
              <NamePartGroup ID="18043" NamePartTypeID="1521" />
            </MasterNamePartGroup>
          </NamePartGroups>
        </Identity>
        <Feature ID="5887" FeatureTypeID="8">
          <FeatureVersion ID="570" ReliabilityID="1">
            <Comment />
            <DatePeriod CalendarTypeID="1" YearFixed="false" MonthFixed="false" DayFixed="false">
              <Start Approximate="true" YearFixed="false" MonthFixed="false" DayFixed="false">
                <From>
                  <Year>1975</Year>
                  <Month>1</Month>
                  <Day>1</Day>
                </From>
                <To>
                  <Year>1975</Year>
                  <Month>1</Month>
                  <Day>1</Day>
                </To>
              </Start>
              <End Approximate="true" YearFixed="false" MonthFixed="false" DayFixed="false">
                <From>
                  <Year>1975</Year>
                  <Month>12</Month>
                  <Day>31</Day>
                </From>
                <To>
                  <Year>1975</Year>
                  <Month>12</Month>
                  <Day>31</Day>
                </To>
              </End>
            </DatePeriod>
            <VersionDetail DetailTypeID="1430" />
          </FeatureVersion>
          <IdentityReference IdentityID="952" IdentityFeatureLinkTypeID="1" />
        </Feature>
        <Feature ID="5888" FeatureTypeID="9">
          <FeatureVersion ID="571" ReliabilityID="1">
            <Comment />
            <VersionDetail DetailTypeID="1432">Damascus, Syria</VersionDetail>
          </FeatureVersion>
          <IdentityReference IdentityID="952" IdentityFeatureLinkTypeID="1" />
        </Feature>
        <Feature ID="164625" FeatureTypeID="25">
          <FeatureVersion ID="214625" ReliabilityID="1">
            <Comment />
            <VersionLocation LocationID="14625" />
          </FeatureVersion>
          <IdentityReference IdentityID="952" IdentityFeatureLinkTypeID="1" />
        </Feature>
        <Feature ID="310569" FeatureTypeID="26">
          <FeatureVersion ID="410569" ReliabilityID="1">
            <Comment />
            <VersionDetail DetailTypeID="1432">Colonel</VersionDetail>
          </FeatureVersion>
          <IdentityReference IdentityID="952" IdentityFeatureLinkTypeID="1" />
        </Feature>
      </Profile>
    </DistinctParty>
```

This is an XML and its root is DistinctParty, now I need to extract two tags from it via JAVA.

1. NamePartyValue
2. VersionDetail

Now I get the root element and can extract NamePartyValue with these methods, but I also need to extract VersionDetail element which I can't even find in the result, could you please direct me in an accurate direction.

```
public NodeList readXMLFileUpdated(String path) {
        File fXmlFile = new File(path);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
        Document doc = null;
        NodeList nList = null;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("DistinctParty");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nList;
    }

public List<Company> getCompanyNamesXML(NodeList nodes){
        List<Company> listOfCompanies = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<nodes.getLength(); i++)
            listOfCompanies.add(new Company(nodes.item(i).getTextContent()));
        return listOfCompanies;
    }
```

This statement **nodes.item(i).getTextContent()** in upper method returns me the value of NamePartyValue field and when trying to get children of this node with this **nodes.item(i).getChildNodes()** I can't see VersionDetail in the result, any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you found the NodeList of "DistincyParty" by calling doc.getElementsByTagName(), you can find VersionDetail or NamePartValue elements by doing the same thing.

Comment: That's the tricky part, Consider DistinctParty as an object and these two as the fields. Now I have a class named DistinctParty and remaining two are fields. I have a huge file with the same structure and I want each of these Distinct Party tags to be an object with these two fields, so If I do like you are saying then it would be messy, I would have created a whole lot of mess to do it, what I require is line to add which gives me VersionDetail like I am getting NamePartValue, so that I can just take them both and put them in an object like new DistinctParty(namePartValue, VersionDetail).

Comment: It looks like a DistinctParty tag in the XML can have multiple NamePartValues underneath. How do you plan on handling that?

Comment: Also, I'm confused as to what you are actually passing into the getCompanyNamesXML method. Even if you had the VersionDetail node described in the example, calling getTextContent on it wouldn't give you anything because that node has no text content. Well at least some of them don't. In the above example, I see three VersionDetail tags and one has no text content.